# Tag synonyms don't give same results in review

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, review

There is the option while reviewing to filter by a tag.  Currently [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [rstats](/questions/tagged/rstats) which are tag synonyms don't give the same results.  I don't see anything when filtering by 'rstats' but get results for 'r'.  It seems that both should return the same results.

Answer (score 1):

When a tag (let's call it [a](/questions/tagged/a)) is made a synonym of another tag (let's call it [b](/questions/tagged/b)), it means:

- Future questions using [a](/questions/tagged/a) will be automatically re-tagged to use [b](/questions/tagged/b)
- Questions asked before [a](/questions/tagged/a) was made a synonym of [b](/questions/tagged/b) still use [a](/questions/tagged/a)

If the synonym must be replaced in all the questions, then:

- [a](/questions/tagged/a) must be made synonym of [b](/questions/tagged/b)
- The tags must be merged

(Moderators do that in the same page, which is the one that allows them to make a tag synonym of another one.)

There could be the case the page showing the questions tagged [a](/questions/tagged/a) is different from the page showing the questions tagged [b](/questions/tagged/b), even if the tags are synonym.

In the case there are no questions tagged [a](/questions/tagged/a), and [a](/questions/tagged/a) is synonym with [b](/questions/tagged/b), then it could be helpful to show the questions tagged [b](/questions/tagged/b). It is probable that is what users want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought this was expected behaviour? As tags are automatically renamed if they are synonyms when the question is posted the [rstats](/questions/tagged/rstats) doesn't exist in the database on any questions so it seems correct that there is nothing to show.

Admittedly I suppose the system could replace a filter of [rstats](/questions/tagged/rstats) with [r](/questions/tagged/r) as you enter it but I'm not sure this would overly useful!

Comment: I guess I would have expected the system to replace rstats with r.  The only reason I have rstats on my list of favorites instead of r is because it's much longer.  With 'r' sometimes I accidentally remove the tag since it's so small.